# java.io.NotSerializableException when @ViewScoped is used

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, view-scope, notserializableexception

If I use `@ViewScoped` in JSF, then the following exception occurs:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.solv.basics.Basics
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    java.util.HashMap.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
```

I can solve it by letting the bean implement `Serializable`. However, I do not understand the reasoning. Why does this exception only occur for the view scope and not the other scopes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't provide the settings from web.xml, but if the `javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD` is set to `client`, the view is always serialized, so the `NotSerializableException` will always occur.

You **should** always make your JSF beans serializable, because application server **may** want to serialize the session, so all session-scoped and view-scoped beans, even if state saving is set to `server`.

But if the server isn't serializing your session, you won't get that error on session scoped beans. But if view is serialized on client, it means that all view scoped beans are serialized to string that is sent as hidden field with all requests, and the JSF engine is detecting that your beans are not serializable.

`NotSerializableException` occurs only when the server tries to actually serialize your beans!

Comment: There's actually one more reason and it's this one which makes MyFaces somewhat different from Mojarra. If you find out this, you get a vote.

Comment: @BalusC: Is it the notion of shallow & deep copy, difference being Mojarra does not  serialize the state in the session with JSF storing only pointers to that specific state in a session.

Comment: @Shirgill: you have asked about this already :) http://stackoverflow.com/q/36574976

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement Serialization in you bean

```
public MyJSFBean implements Serializable{
//Bean coding
}
```

In @ViewScoped bean it is required because the screen data is valid for view not for just one request. In case of @SessionScoped bean data is stored in the session which takes care of serialization of data

Comment: Two same answers have been provided yet.